# How to remove ui-light.css from WinJS build?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, winjs

WinJS or MobileFirst is injecting this piece of code on my index.html, the problem is ui-light.css is messing up with my .css even though it is the very first <link> on the <head>
Is there a way to remove this .css injection? I'd rather avoid doing javascript to remove a code that was just injected by javascript.

```
<script>
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
            if (window.clientInformation.userAgent.indexOf("Windows Phone 8.1") > -1) {
                var fileref1 = document.createElement("script"); 
                var fileref2 = document.createElement("script"); 
                var link = document.createElement('link'); 
                fileref1.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
                fileref1.setAttribute("src", "//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"); 
                fileref2.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
                fileref2.setAttribute("src", "//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js");
                link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"); 
                link.setAttribute("href", "//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/css/ui-light.css"); 
                head.appendChild(fileref1); 
                head.appendChild(fileref2); 
                head.appendChild(link); 
             } else {       
                var fileref1 = document.createElement("script"); 
                var fileref2 = document.createElement("script"); 
                var link = document.createElement("link"); 
                fileref1.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
                fileref1.setAttribute("src", "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js "); 
                fileref2.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
                fileref2.setAttribute("src", "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"); 
                link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"); 
                link.setAttribute("href", "//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-light.css"); 
                head.appendChild(fileref1);
                head.appendChild(fileref2);
                head.appendChild(link);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of winJS was 4.4. The ui-light/dark.css file was included in the WinJS library as a standalone css file. You can choose not to add it if it was messed up with your css. So, please try to update to winJS 4.4.

Comment: Hi @Xavier, thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately I can't move away from this version (2.0) due to other project dependencies.